# Insert row into tableview

Tags: ios, uitableview

Is it possible to insert new rows into tableview dynamicly?.I have Two textfields and When I click on the insert button ,I get data added to my tableview

Comment: Possible. Please use [google](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=insert+new+rows+ios&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla:ml:official&client=firefox-a&channel=np&source=hp&gws_rd=cr)

Answer (score 0):

Sure! Just update your model and then issue:

```
[tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: But how to insert these data into the array in order to reload data of tableview

Comment: If you want the button click to add a row: (1) have your button "wired" to one of your view controller methods, (2) in the method (the 'IBAction') that gets called by your button tap, just add a new object to your model (probably a NSMutableArray in this example), (3) then call the reloadData method on your tableView. This all assumes that you have your tableView already set up with its dataSource configured to be your view controller.

Comment: the object that I want to add to the NSmutablearray must be done Dynamiclly.I have not to use : [myNsmutableArray addobject: @"myobject",nil]; this object must be added depending on what you insert into the textfield

Comment: Correct. In your case, it would be something like: [myMutableArray addObject:[myTextField text]];